# Unable to login into application through automation using selenium without adding compatibility view settings in IE

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer, compatibility

I want to login into application through automation without adding compatibility view settings in IE. But the automation is stopping at login page by not entering any username and password. With compatibility view setting I am able to login. But I am unable to see menus in the application in this scenario. I am able to see menus without adding compatibility settings. The final thing is I should be able to login without adding compatibility view through automation using java. Could anybody please help me on this ?

```
driver=new InternetExplorerDriver();

driver.manage().window().maximize();

driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

ngdriver = new NgWebDriver((JavascriptExecutor)driver);
driver.get(LocatorValues.getProperty("url"));
fis=new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+. 
("\\src\\main\\java\\ExcelData\\Exceldata.xls"));
workbook=new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
Sheet=workbook.getSheet("login");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);

WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='LoginForm:txtUname']")));


driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='LoginForm:txtUname']")).click();
String username_Excel=Sheet.getRow(1).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
        element.sendKeys(username_Excel);
Thread.sleep(1000);

    getxpath("userName").sendKeys(username_Excel);

getxpath("userName").sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
String password=Sheet.getRow(1).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
getxpath("password").sendKeys(password);

getxpath("password").sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Comment: Can the website be logged in without adding compatibility settings when you directly open it in IE (not use selenium automation)? Is there any error showing when it doesn't log in using selenium automation? Besides, it could be better if you can provide the url of the application so that we can investigate deeper.

Comment: Thanks for the response.i have used javascript executor to send the data for login page and now it's working fine.

Comment: Glad that you have solved the issue. You can put your solution as an answer and mark it as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: sure. Will put solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearing the cache in IE everytime before doing automation is worked for me.